# Using fragment for ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to populate my `ListView` with Items from an XML-File.

I know its because I use`Fragments`, but i don't really know how i can fix it.

StackTrace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iklikla.codetechblog/com.iklikla.codetechblog.FrontpageActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
            at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:273)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
            at com.iklikla.codetechblog.FrontpageActivity.onCreate(FrontpageActivity.java:56)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

My Activity:

```
public class FrontpageActivity extends ListActivity {

    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://blog.codetech.de/rss";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_LINK = "link";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_frontpage);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list,
                new String[] { KEY_TITLE, KEY_LINK }, new int[] {
                R.id.textView, R.id.textView2 });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();
        // listening to single listitem click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView)).getText().toString();
                String link = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, title);
                in.putExtra(KEY_LINK, link);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.frontpage, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        switch (itemId)
        {
            case R.id.action_reload:
                Intent intent_reload = new Intent(this, FrontpageActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent_reload);
                break;
            case R.id.action_about:
                Intent intent_about = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent_about);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frontpage, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

And my fragment XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.iklikla.codetechblog.FrontpageActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:background="@color/background_grey">

    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/tutorialTitle"
    android:background="@drawable/card"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: Here is my activity_frontpage.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.iklikla.codetechblog.FrontpageActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Comment: show us `activity_frontpage.xml`

Comment: check my answer you do not have a listview with id as shown in my post in `activity_frontpage.xml`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FrontpageActivity extends ListActivity
```

In `activity_frontpage.xml` you should have  coz your activity extends `ListActivity` and you have  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_frontpage)` in `onCreate`

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Edit:

If you need `ListView` in `Fragment`. You got it all wrong. `Fragment` is hosted by a `Activity`. You need to move all your code to fragment and use a asynctask for gettign xml from server. Rest all is self explanatory i guess.

Links you should check

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
public class FrontpageActivity  extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_frontpage);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new MyFragment())
                    .commit();

    }
}
```

MyFragment

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {
       static final String URL = "http://blog.codetech.de/rss";
        // XML node keys
        static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
        static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
        static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
        private static final String ns = null;
        ListView lv;
        List<Entry> all = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        ProgressDialog pd;

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment1, container, false);
                pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pd.setMessage("Getting xml and parsing...");
                return rootView;
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                 lv = getListView();
                 new TheTask(getActivity()).execute();
            }
            class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,ArrayList<Entry>,ArrayList<Entry>>
            {
             Context context;
             TheTask(Context context)
             {
                 this.context = context;
             }
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Entry> result) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    pd.dismiss();
                    CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(context,result);
                    lv.setAdapter(cus);
                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int arg2, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(context, "text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    });
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pd.show();
                }

                @Override
                protected ArrayList<Entry> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try
                    {
                     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                     httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                     HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
                     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
                     HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                     String _respons=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                     InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(_respons.getBytes());
                     XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
                     parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                     parser.setInput(is, null);
                     parser.nextTag();
                     all =readFeed(parser);
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return (ArrayList<Entry>) all;
                }

            }
            private List<Entry>  readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
                List<Entry> all = null ;
                parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "rss");
                while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String name = parser.getName();
                    // Starts by looking for the entry tag
                    if (name.equals("channel")) {

                       all= readItem(parser);
                    } else {
                        skip(parser);
                    }
                }  
               return all;
            }
            private List<Entry> readItem(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
                List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
                parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "channel");
                while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String name = parser.getName();
                    // Starts by looking for the entry tag
                    if (name.equals("item")) {

                        entries.add(readEntry(parser));
                    } else {
                        skip(parser);
                    }
                }  
                return entries;
            }

            private Entry readEntry(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
                parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "item");
                String title = null;
                String link = null;
                while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String name = parser.getName();
                    if (name.equals("title")) {
                        title = readTitle(parser);
                    } else if (name.equals("link")) {
                        link = readLink(parser);
                    } else {
                        skip(parser);
                    }
                }
                return new Entry(title, link);
            }

            // Processes title tags in the feed.
            private String readTitle(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
                parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "title");

                String title = readText(parser);
                parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "title");
                Log.i("..............",title);
                return title;
            }

            // Processes link tags in the feed.
            private String readLink(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
                String link = "";
                parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "link");

//              String tag = parser.getName();
                link =readText(parser);
//              String relType = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "rel");  
//              if (tag.equals("link")) {
//                  if (relType.equals("alternate")){
//                      link = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "href");
//                      parser.nextTag();
//                  } 
//              }
                parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "link");
                Log.i("..............",link);
               // map.put(KEY_LINK, link);
                return link;
            }

            // For the tags title and summary, extracts their text values.
            private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
                String result = "";
                if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    result = parser.getText();
                    parser.nextTag();
                }
                return result;
            }


 private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        int depth = 1;
        while (depth != 0) {
            switch (parser.next()) {
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                depth--;
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                depth++;
                break;
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

my_fraagment1.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.iklikla.codetechblog.FrontpageActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    >

    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Entry.java

```
public class Entry {
    public final String title;
    public final String link;

    Entry(String title, String link) {
        this.title = title;
        this.link = link;
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private LayoutInflater minflater;
    ArrayList<Entry> entry;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Entry> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        minflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.entry=result;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return entry.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView =minflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder= (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.tv1.setText(entry.get(position).title);
        holder.tv2.setText(entry.get(position).link);
        return convertView;
    }
static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView tv1,tv2;
}
}
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap Shot

[image]

Comment: So i should cut the ListView from the fragment xml to the activity xml?

Comment: @AndreasHeimann yes you need to have listview in activity coz your activity extends `ListActivity`

Comment: @AndreasHeimann you got it all wrong with fragment and activity

Comment: @AndreasHeimann error is pretty clear network operation on the ui thread. use a thread or asynctask and remember fragment is hosted by the activity. you got it all wrong by extending ListActivity should extend activity and need to move all your list code to fragment. keep activity_frontpage.xml as it is

Comment: The Only thing i got wrong now is this:
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                    R.layout.list,
                    new String[] { KEY_TITLE, KEY_LINK }, new int[] {
                    R.id.textView, R.id.textView2 });

The Error is: SimpleAdapter() in SimpleAdapter cannot be applied to

Comment: @AndreasHeimann check the constructor for SimpleAdapter from the docs. But the code will run in Activtiy not fragment. Your Fragment is useless

Comment: @AndreasHeimann pls check the edit now. I answered your question full with snap shot. copy paste understand the code and read the docs for `Asynctask`, `ListActivity` and google search for CustomListView for examples.

Comment: @AndreasHeimann i din't post the entry class. check the edit now and does it work??