# xml parsing and show the data in a list view

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have a xml file like [`this`][1]  and i need to get the all the `"edition name"` according to the `"group name"`

I have to create a list of group name and show the list of editions name on clicking of the group name.
OutPut :

[image]

onclick of catalogs :

[image]

this xml is present in different languages, is there any way to get all the editions name without comparing with group name.

currently i am using type tag to get all the catalogs 
:

```
if(parser.getValue(ele2, "type").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("catalog"))
```

But some `magazines` are also present in `catalogs` type. so not getting correct results 
..

How to get all the `editions name` where `group name` is `catalogs` and so on ...

Or a better way to do so.. I am not sure the code I am using is a good approach. 
Kindly suggest.

My code :

```
final String URL = "http://xml/web/?frg="+lang+"&user="+count+"_"+user;
                System.out.println("URL child : " + URL);
                parser = new XMLParser();
                String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
                doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element


                NodeList n1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("groups");

                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) { //ToDo : worked temp
                    Element e = (Element) n1.item(0);
                    NodeList children = e.getChildNodes();


                    if(item_name.equalsIgnoreCase("Catalogs")||item_name.equalsIgnoreCase("Kataloge")) // there could be other languages
                    {

                        NodeList nodeList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("edition");
                        for (int k = 0; k < nodeList2.getLength(); k++) {
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            Element ele2 = (Element) nodeList2.item(k);
                            if(parser.getValue(ele2, "type").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("catalog"))
                            {
                                System.out.println(""+parser.getValue(ele2, "name").toString());
                                System.out.println(""+parser.getValue(ele2, "cat_url").toString());
                                map.put(ss2,  parser.getValue(ele2,ss2 ));
                                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(ele2, KEY_THUMB_URL));
                                map.put(CAT_URL, parser.getValue(ele2,"cat_url"));
                                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                songsList.add(map);
                            }
                        }


                    }
                    if(item_name.equalsIgnoreCase("Magazines")||item_name.equalsIgnoreCase("Magazine"))
                    {

                        NodeList nodeList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("edition");
                        for (int k = 0; k < nodeList2.getLength(); k++) {
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            Element ele2 = (Element) nodeList2.item(k);
                            if(parser.getValue(ele2, "type").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("pdf"))

                            {
                                System.out.println(""+parser.getValue(ele2, "name").toString());
                                System.out.println(""+parser.getValue(ele2, "cat_url").toString());
                                map.put(ss2,  parser.getValue(ele2,ss2 ));
                                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(ele2, KEY_THUMB_URL));
                                map.put(CAT_URL, parser.getValue(ele2,"cat_url"));
                                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                songsList.add(map);
                            }
                        }



                    }

                    if(item_name.equalsIgnoreCase("Instructions"))
                    {


                        NodeList n2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("groups");

                        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 1; i1++) { //ToDo : worked temp
                            Element e1 = (Element) n2.item(0);
                            NodeList children1 = e1.getChildNodes();

                            for (int j = 0; j <children1.getLength(); j++) {
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                child = children1.item(j);

                                //   System.out.println("name node22 inside " + parser.getValue((Element)child, "name"));
                                if(parser.getValue((Element)child, "name").equals("Instructions"))
                                {

                                    if (child.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("group")) {
                                        NodeList nl2 = child.getChildNodes();
                                        System.out.println("Nodelist lenght : " + nl2.getLength());
                                        for (int jj = 0; jj <nl2.getLength(); jj++) {


                                            Node nn =nl2.item(jj);
                                            System.out.println("name node22 inside " + parser.getValue((Element)nn, "name"));

                                        }

                                        //  map.put(KEY_TITLE,  parser.getValue((Element)child,KEY_TITLE ));
                                        //map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue((Element)child, KEY_THUMB_URL));

                                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                        //songsList.add(map);

                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }



                    }
```

Solved : 
Changed this :

```
Element e = (Element) n1.item(0);
NodeList nodeList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("edition");
```

to this :

```
Element e = (Element) n1.item(0);
NodeList nodeList2 = e.getElementsByTagName("edition");
```

Comment: check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455890/using-fragment-for-listview/20455968#20455968. using xml pullparser and ListFragment.

Comment: thanks i'll check ,could you help me on getting all the editions name where group name is catalogs and so on ... ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather suggest you to build your own parser using the pattern matching approach. Coz it gives you the power to customize things according to your need. 
Gson like parser will be a good fit.